# Flatten numpy array but also keep index of value positions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have several 2D numpy arrays (matrix) and for each one I would like to convert it to vector containing the values of the array and a vector containing each row/column index.

For example I might have an array like this:

```
x = np.array([[3, 1, 4],
              [1, 5, 9],
              [2, 6, 5]])
```

and I basically want the values

```
[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5]
```

and their position

```
[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [1,0], [1,1], [1,2], [2,0], [2,1], [2,2]]
```

My end goal is to put these into a pandas DataFrame as columns like this:

```
V | x | y
--+---+---
3 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 1
4 | 0 | 2
1 | 1 | 0
5 | 1 | 1
9 | 1 | 2
6 | 2 | 0
5 | 2 | 1
3 | 2 | 2
```

where V is the value, x is the row position (index), and y is the column position (index).

I think I can hack something together but I'm trying to find the efficient way of doing this rather than fumbling around. For example I know I can get the values using something like `x.reshape(x.size, 1)` and that I could try to create the index columns from `x.shape`, but there seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: I think `reshape` executes in constant time and for creating the indexes you only need a single `for`.

Comment: What do you mean only a single `for`? I understand that `reshape` is about as efficient as it gets.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if it's most efficient, but [`numpy.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) is designed for this:

```
x = np.array([[3, 1, 4],
              [1, 5, 9],
              [2, 6, 5]])
XX,YY = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x.shape[1]),np.arange(x.shape[0]))
table = np.vstack((x.ravel(),XX.ravel(),YY.ravel())).T
print(table)
```

This produces:

```
[[3 0 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [4 2 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [5 1 1]
 [9 2 1]
 [2 0 2]
 [6 1 2]
 [5 2 2]]
```

Then I think `df = pandas.DataFrame(table)` will give you your desired data frame.

Answer (score 7):

You could also let pandas do the work for you since you'll be using it in a dataframe:

```
x = np.array([[3, 1, 4],
              [1, 5, 9],
              [2, 6, 5]])
df=pd.DataFrame(x)
#unstack the y columns so that they become an index then reset the
#index so that indexes become columns.
df=df.unstack().reset_index()
df

   level_0  level_1  0
0        0        0  3
1        0        1  1
2        0        2  2
3        1        0  1
4        1        1  5
5        1        2  6
6        2        0  4
7        2        1  9
8        2        2  5

#name the columns and switch the column order
df.columns=['x','y','V']
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
df = df[cols]
df

   V  x  y
0  3  0  0
1  1  0  1
2  2  0  2
3  1  1  0
4  5  1  1
5  6  1  2
6  4  2  0
7  9  2  1
8  5  2  2
```

Comment: Wha? You can do this?!

Comment: This is pure magic! Thank you so much for opening our eyes to this!

Answer (score 3):

The class `np.ndindex` is especially meant for this, and easily does the trick. Similar efficiency to the `np.mesgrid` method above, but it requires less code:

```
indices = np.array(list(np.ndindex(x.shape)))
```

For the dataframe, do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'V': x.flatten(), 'x': indices[:, 0], 'y': indices[:, 1]})
```

If you don't need the dataframe, just do `list(np.ndindex(x.shape))`.

Note: don't get confused between `x` (the array at hand), and `'x'` (the name of the second column).

I know this question was posted a very long time ago, but just in case it's useful to anyone, as I didn't see `np.ndindex` being mentioned.

Comment: `np.ndindex` is ridiculously slow. Comparing `list(np.ndindex(shape))` vs `np.array(np.where(np.ones(shape))).T` (pretty dummy code, right?), I got the dummy solution about 5 times faster for a `(4, 4, 4)` shape, 10 times faster for a `(10, 10, 10)` shape, and I let you guess where it is going for large ndarray!

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
arr = np.array([[3, 1, 4],
                [1, 5, 9],
                [2, 6, 5]])

# build out rows array
x = np.arange(arr.shape[0]).reshape(arr.shape[0],1).repeat(arr.shape[1],axis=1)
# build out columns array
y = np.arange(arr.shape[1]).reshape(1,arr.shape[0]).repeat(arr.shape[0],axis=0)

# combine into table
table = np.vstack((arr.reshape(arr.size),x.reshape(arr.size),y.reshape(arr.size))).T
print(table)
```

Comment: With `x,y = np.mgrid[0:arr.shape[0],0:arr.shape[0]]` you have the same result as `np.arange(...`.
+1 For the creative solution with vstack, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Update November 2020 (tested on pandas v1.1.3 and numpy v1.19):

This should be a no-brainer by using [np.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and `.reshape(-1)`.

```
x = np.array([[3, 1, 4],
              [1, 5, 9]])

x_coor, y_coor = np.meshgrid(range(x.shape[1]), range(x.shape[0]))    
df = pd.DataFrame({"V": x.reshape(-1), "x": x_coor.reshape(-1), "y": y_coor.reshape(-1)})
```

For 2-dimensional cases, you don't even need a meshgrid. Just [np.tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) the range of the column axis and [np.repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for the row axis.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "V": x.reshape(-1),
    "x": np.tile(np.arange(x.shape[1]), x.shape[0]),
    "y": np.repeat(np.arange(x.shape[0]), x.shape[1])
})
```

The sample data is trimmed to `shape=(2, 3)` to better reflect the axes location.

**Result**

```
print(df)

   V  x  y
0  3  0  0
1  1  1  0
2  4  2  0
3  1  0  1
4  5  1  1
5  9  2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use loops.

```
x = np.array([[3, 1, 4],
              [1, 5, 9],
              [2, 6, 5]])
values = []
coordinates = []
data_frame = []
for v in xrange(len(x)):
    for h in xrange(len(x[v])):
        values.append(x[v][h])
        coordinates.append((h, v))
        data_frame.append(x[v][h], h, v)
        print '%s | %s | %s' % (x[v][h], v, h)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `itertools`

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def convert2dataframe(array):
    a, b = array.shape
    x, y = zip(*list(itertools.product(range(a), range(b))))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'V':array.ravel(), 'x':x, 'y':y})
    return df
```

This works for arrays of any shape, not necessarily square matrices.

Answer (score 0):

I am resurrecting this because I think I know a different answer that is way easier to understand. Here is how I do it:

```
xn = np.zeros((np.size(x), np.ndim(x)+1), dtype=np.float32)
row = 0
for ind, data in np.ndenumerate(x):
    xn[row, 0] = data
    xn[row, 1:] = np.asarray(ind)
    row += 1
```

In `xn` we have

```
[[ 3.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 4.  0.  2.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.]
 [ 5.  1.  1.]
 [ 9.  1.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  0.]
 [ 6.  2.  1.]
 [ 5.  2.  2.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @miguel-capllonch I would suggest using `np.ndindex` which allows you to create the desired output like this:

```
np.array([(v, *i) for (i, v) in zip(np.ndindex(x.shape), x.ravel())])
```

which results in an array that looks like this:

```
array([[ 3.  0.  0.]
       [ 1.  0.  1.]
       [ 4.  0.  2.]
       [ 1.  1.  0.]
       [ 5.  1.  1.]
       [ 9.  1.  2.]
       [ 2.  2.  0.]
       [ 6.  2.  1.]
       [ 5.  2.  2.]])
```

---

Alternatively, using only numpy commands

```
np.hstack((list(np.ndindex(x.shape)), x.reshape((-1, 1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a concatenation between `x.ravel()` and the cartesian indices:

```
np.c_[x.ravel(), np.c_[np.repeat(np.r_[:3], 3), np.tile(np.r_[:3], 3)]]
```

Output:

```
array([[3, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [4, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [5, 1, 1],
       [9, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [6, 2, 1],
       [5, 2, 2]])
```