# Flatten a matrix into an array containing the index positions of the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Given a numpy matrix, `my_matrix`.

```
import numpy as np

my_matrix = np.array([[1.2,2.3,None],[4.5,3.4,9.3]])
```

How can you efficiently flatten it into the following array containing the index positions of `my_matrix`?

```
[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]]
```

Comment: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081067/flatten-numpy-array-but-also-keep-index-of-value-positions) question however I'm not looking to create a dataframe.

Comment: How is the content of `my_matrix` important? The index list you provided would be valid for each 2x3 matrix, right?

Comment: And: Do you need the resulting index list for indexing? If so, there may be a more efficient alternative approach.

Comment: The matrix contains values that in obtained from a .tif file imported from the [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package.

I would like to [map a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array) on the array of index locations which will return an array of lat and lon positions.

Comment: If you want to literally `map` a function, it may be beneficial to use a generator for the indices rather than using a list.

Comment: Thanks, but I've never used a generator. rusu_ro1s solution is working well for my use case.
`[func_pixle_to_coords(jj, ii) for ii in range(rows) for jj in range(cols)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
rows, cols = my_matrix.shape
[[i, j] for i in range(rows) for j in range(cols)]
```

output:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.indices()` and reshape the returned values a little bit

```
np.indices(my_matrix.shape).transpose(1, 2, 0).reshape(-1, 2)
# array([[0, 0],
#        [0, 1],
#        [0, 2],
#        [1, 0],
#        [1, 1],
#        [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create such a list easily with pure python:

```
from itertools import product
list(product(range(my_matrix.shape[0]), range(my_matrix.shape[1])))
```

Result is

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

If you are not using the explicit list but only want to iterate over the indices, leave the `list(...)` away. This will save memory and computation time, as the indices will be generated when they are used only.

However, if you want to use the result to index a numpy array, it may be more convenient to use `np.ix_`:

```
np.ix_(np.arange(my_matrix.shape[0]), np.arange(my_matrix.shape[1]))
```

Output is

```
(array([[0],
        [1]]), array([[0, 1, 2]]))
```